# Predict in R after GLM

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, predict

I trained   my model on 6000 training sample (glm)
Then, I tried predict for vector with 200000 rows,
But as a result I received only 6000 rows.

I used these arguments for the function predict():

```
     predict(                       
object = model_ppp2,
newdate = Model_education, 
type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
se.fit = TRUE, 
dispersion = NULL, 
terms = NULL,
na.action = na.pass
)
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to provide more details, for example your codes. Now what I could guess is that you didn't specify the arguments `newdata = ` in your `predict()` function. If you didn't define `newdata`, it will do an in sample predict.

Comment: It really would have just made a lot more sense to post the actual command you used.

Comment: `newdata=` not `newdate=`

Comment: Thank you, but I define "newdata=" already:
predict(
                                object = model_ppp2,
                                newdate = Model_education, 
                                type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
                                se.fit = TRUE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
                                na.action = na.pass
                                )

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I also invite you to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be

```
predict(                       
 object = model_ppp2,
 newdata = Model_education, 
 type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
 se.fit = TRUE, 
 dispersion = NULL, 
 terms = NULL,
 na.action = na.pass
)
```

so `newdatA` instead of `newdatE`